# User can't delete DateTime in old Infragistics UltraGrid

Tags: datetime, infragistics, dbnull, ultrawingrid

I'm working on an older application now which uses Infragistics UltraGrid v3.1.

In the UltraGrid the user can enter a date (with mask ____/____/_____). If there is already a date in the cell and the user wants to clear it, he'll get an error when he leaves the cell ("Unable to update the data value: Value in the editor is not valid") . When there is a DBNull value in the database the UltraGrid just shows an empty cell.
If I click on an empty date cell the mask appears, when I leave this cell then there is no problem (Even if I selected the whole mask and delete it). The problem starts once I've entered some value (Or a value was already placed.)

I want the user to be able to clear the date so that the cell will be empty again.

I've tried to set the value of the active cell in the ultragrid_Error event to DBNull.Value . But then I get this exception:

Internal error: can't get masked editor value.

Inner exception: Input does not match the mask.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Have you tried with a simple `null`?

Comment: Yes, well I tried Nothing (it's a vb.net application). Then I get another exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: I tested with UltraGrid v3.1 file version 3.1.20041.1046 and I didn't reproduced the issue that you have when bound to a DataTable that has a DateTime column.  Do you have any specific format set on the column?  What is the list that you are binding the grid to?  Do you have some code that may help to reproduce the issue?